# REST API: Best practices to update an array of JSON objects

Tags: json, rest

I have the following JSON object:

```
{
   cars: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: test1
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: test2
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: test3
      }
   ]
}
```

I would like to create an new API that use this JSON object to update the name of all cars provided in the JSON cars structure.

- What is the best practice to do that ? Use a POST, a PUT ?
- I imagine that the url could be: POST or PUT /cars ? (Without id in params)
- I would like to check if all cars really exists before updating them, do i need to send a 404 NOT Found in response if one of them is not defined ?**

Thanks for your recomendation

Comment: Definitely it would be a PUT request with a body response with the number of updated rows. At least I would do it that way.

Comment: HTTP isn't ideal for batch processings. I.e. a batch update of a collection does not automatically imply that all of the affected entries need to be invalidated in a certain (intermediary) cache. Clients therefore might still get served by the cache while the information is already outdated. As caching is a constraint and not an option you add if you feel like in REST, you should probably design your system to coop with caching. [Pipelining](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-6.3.2) could be used to send multiple request over the same connection to fake a batch update though